# Why is my flash drive not supported after formatting to fat32?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a 4 gb flash drive that I use as a bootable usb to install ubuntu, but now I want to unboot and format the file system, I try it through ubuntu's gparted, but when using it on devices that used to work without any problem, now he can't stand them.

It is worth mentioning that I formatted the USB and I did the partitioning with gparteda fat32 format, I also tried it with other formats and everything remains the same.

if someone can help me.

there is the information of the usb.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *there is the information of the usb.* - looks fine

Comment: Please **edit** your posting and tell what you see - in detail, make sure to get past / beyond "it does not work" which would not help here. This is likely to get closed unless you can create meaningful info.

Comment: I have moved away my answer to https://superuser.com/q/1784021/346288 - as you indicated that it did not suit your problem.